# How to reduce execution time for sum product calculation?

Tags: excel, vba, performance, sumproduct

When I execute the code on more than 10 thousand records it takes approximately 15 to 25 minutes.

This code puts a mark to then make a filter and generate a trend graph with the values 1 and 0.

How could I improve the code so it takes less time to execute?

```vb
Sub Flags()

    Dim wSht As Worksheet
    Set wSht = ActiveSheet

    'New_Columns_Calculation

    With wSht.Range("HI2:HI" & wSht.Cells(Rows.Count, "HH").End(xlUp).Row)
        .Formula = "=IF(SUMPRODUCT(($HF$2:HF2=HF2) * ($HG$2:HG2=HG2))>1,0,1)"
        .Value = .Value 'We convert the formula to values
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a go at a few different things here (turning calculations off and splitting the formula and value past as well as doing this as a VBA operation).

Honestly none of them availed much on my test set (two columns of 20,000 random numbers).

This being said I think it might be worth you trying the array option; full disclosure this was slower on my test than your code but I think will be less susceptible to the problem of having so many columns of data as you do.

obviously only do this on a test data set and validate to your code to ensure its working

```
Sub FlagsArray()

    Dim wSht As Worksheet, rng As Range, myArray(), arrayOut() As Variant
    Set wSht = ActiveSheet
    Set rng = wSht.Range("A2:B" & wSht.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    
    myArray = rng.Value
    ReDim arrayOut(1 To UBound(myArray), 0)
    
    
    arrayOut(1, 0) = 1
    
    For i = 2 To UBound(myArray)
        arrayOut(i, 0) = 1
        For j = 1 To i - 1
            If myArray(j, 1) = myArray(i, 1) And myArray(j, 2) = myArray(i, 2) Then
                arrayOut(i, 0) = 0
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    
    wSht.Range("C2:C" & wSht.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row) = arrayOut()

End Sub
```

Please let me know how you get on with this as I'm amazed I couldn't make more progress on this one and I'm holding out hope that this works on the bigger set you have!

Comment: Hello @InjuredCoding thank you very much for your answer.  What you present to me is a very good one and the processing time is less than my code.  However, the result is not the expected result of the SUMPRODUCT formula, the process only results in the value of 1. With the SUMPRODUCT formula I do get 1 and 0 as a result. Thank you very much for your prompt response.

Comment: ok sorry daft array error, edited and it should now work. please let me know if its quicker and by roughly how much and accept the answer if its helped :)

Comment: Works perfectly. He did the test with a set of 29k records and it only took 33 seconds to run. Thank you very much for your support and time, great job! Now I just have to break down your code to learn it in detail.

Just one final QUESTION:

How can I adapt your code if the ranges are in separate columns, that is:

=IF(SUMPRODUCT(($C$2:C2=C2) * ($J$2:J2=J2))>1,0,1)?

Comment: i'm glad it worked, that sounds like a good improvement!  which I had hoped but my Mock up didn't seem to deliver.  To your question:  Change `rng` to only pull the one column (i.e. `rng = wSht.Range("A2:A" & wSht.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)` create an `rng2` that has the other column in it.  Create a second array `myArray2` that takes as an input `rng2` instead of `rng` (i.e. `myArray2 = rng2.Value`) then wherever `myArray(.... , 2)` is replace with `myArray2(.... , 1)`.  sounds like a bit but if you work through step by step should be doable & may help your understanding

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response, your second solution worked correctly.

Just one final question. In this line it is not necessary to do anything "ReDim arrayOut(1 To UBound(myArray), 0) arrayOut(1, 0) = 1". 

Or in this part "For i = 2 To UBound(myArray)"

Comment: no, assuming the two tables are the same length.  if they are not then this code will have a lot of problems!  those two are basically just getting how many rows there are in the table.